# Creating Tables

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

Suppose you have the following database:

```
Person(ssn NUMERIC(9), name VARCHAR(40), gender CHAR(1)), ssn is primary key

Organization(org_code CHAR(4), budget INTEGER, org_name VARCHAR(60)), org_code is primary key

Person_Organization(ssn, org_code), both columns are the primary key.
```

Are the keys in the person_organization table considered foreign keys or primary keys? I am stuck on how to create this table. Have tried looking in my textbooks but cannot find information about it. I don't know if they are supposed to be foreign keys that reference the primary keys or if I should just do this

```
CREATE TABLE person_organization(ssn NUMERIC(9), org_code VARCHAR(60));
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simple answer is that they're both.

`ssn, org_code` should be the primary key of `person_organization`.

`ssn` should be a foreign key back into person and `org_code` should by a foreign key back into `organization`.

To separate myself from [northpole's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9491108/458741) I don't actually agree with the surrogate key argument in this case it doesn't seem to be needed as it won't be used anywhere else.

Unfortunately the problem with this (good) solution to the many to many relationship is that it's often needed to have two unique keys on a table, `ssn, org_code` **and** `org_code, ssn` and choose one as the primary key.

---

As you're using Oracle the create table syntax would be

```
create table person_organization
( ssn number(9)
, org_code varchar2(60)
, constraint person_organization_pk primary key (ssn, org_code)
, constraint person_organization_ssn_fk foreign key ( ssn )
    references person ( ssn )
, constraint person_organization_oc_fk foreign key ( org_code )
    references organization ( org_code )
 );
```

In your original table creation script you had `ssn` as `numeric(9)`, which should by `number(9)`. You may want to consider not restricting the size of this data type. You also had `org_code` as a `varchar`, this should probably be a `varchar2`.

[Tech on the Net](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/index.php) is a really good resource for learning syntax.

Comment: that is part of the reason why I like to create these intersect tables with it's own primary key.  Then you can just keep the two other foreign keys as just a multi-column unique identifier.  But either way is fine. +1, for probably the most common design.

Comment: @northpole, if you disagree there's definitely no need to +1 :-).

Comment: no, I don't disagree at all, I just do things a little differently.  Your suggestion is good and is probably the most commonly used solution.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on the website Ben. Also as for the syntax, I got this mapping from my Professor. I was just asking a question based on a document he provided. Thanks for the tips though. I will keep that in mind for the future. I'm assuming he prob wrote them this way because he is old school? Not sure. Anyhow. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest adding a unique, auto incrementing primary key to PERSON_ORGANIZATION (called something like po_id) as well as the two FOREIGN keys of ssn and org_code.  You can also make those two unique if you want.  From my experience, I like to have almost every table have it's own unique/auto key (unless it is a lookup table or audit table (and possibly others)).

Answer (score 0):

They're both.

For the person_organization table you would have a compound primary key that consisted of the two columns. Each is separately a foreign key to another table.

For normal database design they should reference the primary keys in the other tables and these constraints enforce the validity of the data in the database.

Answer (score 0):

They are foreign keys.

You've listed "both columns are the primary key" but I don't think they are.

The table does not have a primary key.
The combination of the two fields is certainly acting as a proxy for a primary key, doing things like making sure entries are uniquely identified and thus acting together as a unique identifier but that is a bit different.

I would also recommend adding a separate primary key field for consistency with the structure of others tables. As with other tables I recommend always using either id [my favorite] or tablename_id

Answer (score 0):

This is the basic idea, you need to provide proper datatype for each field

```
CREATE TABLE Persons (
  ssn int(9) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  name varchar(40),
  gender CHAR(1)
)

CREATE TABLE Organization (
  org_code CHAR(4)NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  budget INTEGER,
  org_name VARCHAR(60)
)

CREATE TABLE Person_Organization (
  ssn int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Persons(ssn),
  org_code CHAR FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Organization(org_code)
```

)